# Use logarithmic differentiation to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Here is the problem as well as my work so far. Any advice or hints regarding where I should go from here would be appreciated.The arrow indicates where I got stuck.

[image]

Where do I go from here?

### EDIT

I realize my mistake in not using logarithms. Here is my second attempt. What should I try from here?[image]

Comment: You did not use logarithmic differentiation.  First step: $\ln y=5\ln(x^2+3)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x+1)$. Now differentiate both sides.

Comment: did you not read the instruction given in your question? you are asked to find the derivative using logarithmic differentiation. i don't see any logarithms in your answer. take the $\ln$ of $y = \cdots$ before differentiating.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I realize my mistake. Please see my edit; where should I go from here?

Comment: You are misusing the notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$. For example you should have written $\frac{d}{dx}(5\ln(x^2+3))=\frac{10x}{x^2+3}$. But apart from notation troubles, you calculated the derivative of the RHS correctly. Now we differentiate $\ln y$ with respect to $x$. By the Chain Rule, $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln y)=\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}$. Conclude that $\frac{dy}{dx}=y\left(\frac{10x}{x^2+3}-\frac{1}{2(1+x)}\right)$ and replace $y$ by its value in terms of $x$. Then (maybe) simplify a bit.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the notation mistake. Okay, makes sense- I'll try that now.

Comment: @AndréNicolas would you be able to give an answer showing how you would simplify? I understand the steps you explained above but am having trouble simplifying after replacing y with its value in terms of x.

Comment: You are welcome. That notational error is quite frequent. I am being fussy because notational errors often lead to wrong answers. By the way, you had a small mistake at the end of your Quotient Rule calculation (first attempt). Note that $((x+1)^{1/2})^2=x+1$.

Comment: There are lots of ways to simplify. We are multiplying the derivative of the RHS by $(x^2+3)^5(x+1)^{-1/2}$. We get $10x(x^2+3)^4(x+1)^{-1/2}-(1/2)(x^2+3)^5(1+x)^{-3/2}$. Maybe then bring everything to the common denominator $2(x+1)^{3/2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a way to do check your i will do it little differently. i will start with 
$$\ln y = 5 \ln (x^2 + 3) - \frac 12 \ln (x+1) $$ differencing this we get $$\frac{dy}{y} = 5 \frac{d(x^2 + 3)}{x^2 + 3} - \frac{d(x+1)}{2(x+1)}=\frac{10x\, dx}{x^2 + 3} - \frac{dx}{2(x+1)} $$ therefore 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y\left(\frac{10x}{x^2 + 3} - \frac{1}{2(x+1)}\right)= \frac{(x^2+3)^3}{\sqrt{x+1}}\left(\frac{10x}{x^2 + 3} - \frac{1}{2(x+1)}\right)=\frac{(x^2+3)^2(19x^2+20x - 3)}{2(x+1)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Thanks. Could you simplify this further? I want to make sure I simplified correctly...

Comment: @McB, as far as it can go, i believe.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!